# Introducing kids to namaz as a regular

Tags: salat, practical-islam, islamic-basis

What is the right way to make kid who turned 8 pray regularly? Fajr is early so they are sleeping, at zhur they r at school, they come back at asr. What is the way Islam has mentioned to make kids regular at namaz, especially the time they are at school.

How to start?